# Configure files to come from a central location unless that file has been customized for a specific site

Tags: apache, files, vhost

I have an user A on a server, this users has a working set of scripts (html+js+css+everything else).
I also have users B-[as much as I want]. I want those to use the exact same files, **but** if they have the file themselves, use that. Like a multi-user `file_exists()` on server level.

Say the user B has `/templates/index.html`, I want the site to use all over User A's files, apart from that template (which is User B's). Much like an alias, until a file exists.

Could anyone point my in the right direction, I'm able to work on server level, I simply don't know the terms, I don't know what I'm looking for.

---

**Example**:

```
USER A                  USER B                      USER C
.htaccess                                           
index.php                                           
/templates/             /templates/                 /templates/
    - index.html                                    
    - header.html           - header.html           
    - footer.html                                   - footer.html
```

USER B uses **all** of USER A's files, apart from `header.html`
USER C uses **all** of USER A's files, apart from `footer.html`

An easy way to explain: User's B&C are an alias of A, apart from the few existing files. Pretty urls have to remain working.

Comment: A suggestion for a better title wouldn't be bad either.

Comment: What's wrong with a scripted solution that uses something like `file_exists()`? Or do you envisage a lower server-level solution?

Comment: Performance and maintanability.

Comment: Are these just static HTML or are we talking portions of a page like included PHP here?

Comment: We use seperate php and html files, there is no php in htmlfiles.

Comment: Are these all intended to be client-side requests? ie. You don't need to conditionally pull files server-side?

Comment: I mainly need to use serverside files

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache webserver you might use:

```
# Turn on redirection module in case not already on
RewriteEngine On
# If requested file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested file is /scripts/script.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ="/scripts/script.php"
# then use the script made available to all users
RewriteRule ^.*$ /scripts-global/script.php [L]
```

Though it is probably worth mentioning that from Apache v2.2 the *-f* test (to see if a file exists) does not work with relative paths so if looking to replace `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` then you'll need to replace it with a full path such as */home/users/martijn*.

Comment: This is proving VERY difficult, in combo with pretty url's, and .htaccess files and everything.

Comment: Rules for the above would best be put at the top of your .htaccess file, ahead of any pretty URL rules.

Comment: You should 1st check for the initial script URL in the `RewriteRule` pattern (instead of the _filename_ in `RewriteCond`). Checking for `^.*$` is inefficient since _every_ request will be processed and it looks like a few of these rule blocks would be required.

Comment: @w3d but surely the way I wrote it, the `RewriteRule` is only executed if the `RewriteCond` expressions (based on known values) are *TRUE*, whereas your method would have to execute alot of `RewriteRule` statements whether they apply or not, suggesting you think executing a `RewriteRule` might be more efficient than a few `RewriteCond` statements? I can believe this perhaps in terms of typing out source code but not performance, though perhaps the performance could be improved slightly by swapping the first two `RewriteCond` statements over so that the script filename check comes first.

Comment: Well, yes and no. mod_rewrite doesn't work strictly top-down as your comments suggest. Apache first checks the `RewriteRule` pattern against the requested URL. Only if the pattern matches does the parser start checking the `RewriteCond` directives above it (otherwise the `RewriteCond` directives are simply ignored and the parser moves on to the next `RewriteRule`). If all the `RewriteCond` directives are satisfied then yes, the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ is made.